# VBA - Find and compare values in multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba

Below is a table with a mock up of the data I have and what I need returned in the last column (AJ). What I am trying to do is look though all rows that have the same value in Column M and then compare the values in the rest of the columns noted below. Return same is all the values are the same, return the name(s) of the column(s) if something is different. I have tried starting for each but have two problems 1) its only comparing to previous row, not sets of rows with same value in column M, 2) I can only figure out how to identify on difference, not multiple. Any help is appreciated

| Col M | Col AE (Name) | Col AF (Date) | Col AG (Active) | Col AH (Dept) | Col AJ (What I want Returned) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1234 | Campaign 1 | Jan 20,2022 | 1 | Marketing | Same |
| A1234 | Campaign 1 | Jan 20,2022 | 1 | Marketing | Same |
| A1234 | Campaign 1 | Jan 20,2022 | 1 | Marketing | Same |
| A4321 | Campaign 2 | Feb 20,2022 | 1 | Marketing | Date |
| A4321 | Campaign 2 | Mar 20,2022 | 1 | Marketing | Date |
| A4321 | Campaign 2 | Feb 20,2022 | 1 | Marketing | Date |
| A4321 | Campaign 2 | Feb 20,2022 | 1 | Marketing | Date |
| A2222 | Campaign 3 | Apr 20,2022 | 1 | Marketing | Name, Active |
| A2222 | Campaign 3 | Apr 20,2022 | 2 | Marketing | Name, Active |
| A2222 | Campaign 33 | Apr 20,2022 | 1 | Marketing | Name, Active |
| A2222 | Campaign 3 | Apr 20,2022 | 1 | Marketing | Name, Active |

'''

```
Sub CheckSame()

Dim i As Integer
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


For i = 3 To lastRow
    If Cells(i, 13) = Cells(i - 1, 13) Then
        If Cells(i, 31) = Cells(i - 1, 31) And Cells(i, 32) = Cells(i - 1, 32) And Cells(i, 33) = Cells(i - 1, 33) And Cells(i, 34) = Cells(i - 1, 34) Then
            Cells(i, 36) = "Same"
        ElseIf Cells(i, 32) = Cells(i - 1, 32) And Cells(i, 33) = Cells(i - 1, 33) And Cells(i, 34) = Cells(i - 1, 34) Then
            Cells(i, 36) = "Name"
        ElseIf Cells(i, 31) = Cells(i - 1, 31) And Cells(i, 33) = Cells(i - 1, 33) And Cells(i, 34) = Cells(i - 1, 34) Then
            Cells(i, 36) = "Date"
        ElseIf Cells(i, 31) = Cells(i - 1, 31) And Cells(i, 32) = Cells(i - 1, 32) And Cells(i, 34) = Cells(i - 1, 34) Then
            Cells(i, 36) = "Active"
        ElseIf Cells(i, 31) = Cells(i - 1, 31) And Cells(i, 32) = Cells(i - 1, 32) And Cells(i, 33) = Cells(i - 1, 33) Then
            Cells(i, 36) = "Dept"
        End If
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

'''

Comment: Are cols AK to AL used ?

Comment: @CDP1802 They do have other data in them, but I can move stuff around if your code needs them to be blank

Comment: The last row in your sample data seems to be the same as the one three rows above. Is the return for these rows ("Name, Active") correct?

Comment: If the code returned the value that occurred the most for each column where should it go ? Or they could go on another sheet, one record for each different Col M value.

Comment: @CDP1802 That would be amazing - it could go in AK forward

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Column AJ should note the differences for any set same values in column M - so because last 4 have the same value in M, it should pick up there is a difference in AE in the second to last and a difference in AG in third to last

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle use 4 dictionaries (1 for each column) to count the number of times a value appears in a group of records.

```vb
Option Explicit
Const SHOWPC = True

Sub CompareCols()

   Const COL_ID = "M"
   Const COL_NAME = "AE"
   Const COL_RESULT = "AJ"

   Dim ws As Worksheet, lastrow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
   Dim arDict, arCol, v, n As Long, msg As String
   arCol = Array("Name", "Date", "Active", "Dept")
   
   ReDim arDict(UBound(arCol)) As Object
   For i = 0 To UBound(arDict)
      Set arDict(i) = CreateObject("Scripting.DIctionary")
   Next
   
   Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
   With ws
      lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, COL_ID).End(xlUp).Row
      For i = 2 To lastrow
         For j = 0 To 3
            v = .Cells(i, "AE").Offset(, j)
            arDict(j)(v) = arDict(j)(v) + 1 ' count of this value
         Next
         n = n + 1
         
         ' is this last in group
         If .Cells(i + 1, COL_ID) <> .Cells(i, COL_ID) Then
             .Cells(i - n + 1, COL_RESULT).Resize(n, 5) = CompareRows(arDict, arCol)
             n = 0
         End If
      Next
   End With
   
   MsgBox lastrow - 1 & " rows scanned", vbInformation
End Sub

Function CompareRows(ByRef arDict, arCol) As Variant
     
    Dim v, s As String, sep As String, pc As String
    Dim n As Long, i As Long, tot As Long, m As Long
     
    n = UBound(arCol) ' cols to check
    Dim arCount: ReDim arCount(n) As Long
    Dim arResult: ReDim arResult(1 To 1, 1 To n + 2)
     
    ' check each column
    For i = 0 To n
        tot = 0
        For Each v In arDict(i).keys
            m = arDict(i)(v) 'count of value
            tot = tot + m
             ' take v with most entries
            If m > arCount(i) Then
                arCount(i) = m
                arResult(1, i + 2) = v
            End If
        Next
         ' add pcent
        If SHOWPC Then
            pc = Format(arCount(i) / tot, " (0%)")
            arResult(1, i + 2) = arResult(1, i + 2) & pc
        End If
     
        If arDict(i).Count > 1 Then
            s = s & sep & arCol(i)
            sep = ","
        End If
        arDict(i).RemoveAll ' clear dictionary
     Next
     If s = "" Then s = "Same"
     arResult(1, 1) = s
     CompareRows = arResult
     
End Function
```

Comment: This is awesome - thanks for the extra work on the most common value!!!! Can I ask for one change? Right now it only populates data for the last row in each set. So in the example above its only populating "Same" for row 3 of the A1234 set. If it could populate for all rows, I can filter out the "Same" values and only work on the ones that have differences.

Comment: You are amazing - you have saved me so much time and I will use your code to learn from!

Answer (score 0):

### Flag Unique Values

[image]

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub FlagUniques()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const WS_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const UNIQUE_COL As String = "M"
    Const RESULT_COL As String = "AJ"
    Const TITLES_LIST As String = "Name,Date,Active,Dept"
    Const TITLE_DELiMITER As String = ","
    Const DUPE_STRING As String = "Same"
    Const UNIQUE_STRING As String = "Unique"
    Const INVALID_STRING As String = "Invalid"
    Const RESULT_DELIMITER As String = ", "
    
    ' Reference the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the range.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(WS_NAME)
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion ' has headers
    Dim hrg As Range: Set hrg = rg.Rows(1) ' header
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count - 1 ' no headers
    Set rg = rg.Resize(rCount).Offset(1) ' no headers
    
    ' Write the values from the unique column to an array (2D one-based).
    Dim uData(): uData = rg.Columns(UNIQUE_COL).Value
    
    ' Split the titles from the list into an array (1D zero-based).
    Dim Titles() As String: Titles = Split(TITLES_LIST, TITLE_DELiMITER)
    ' Match the title indexes into an array (1D one-based).
    Dim tColIndexes(): tColIndexes = Application.Match(Titles, hrg, 0)
    
    ' Write the values from the title columns to a jagged array
    ' (1D one-based, containing 2D one-based single-column arrays).
    
    Dim tCount As Long: tCount = UBound(tColIndexes)
    Dim tJag(): ReDim tJag(1 To tCount)
    
    Dim t As Long
    
    For t = 1 To tCount
        tJag(t) = rg.Columns(tColIndexes(t)).Value
    Next t
    
    ' Write the unique values from the unique array to the 'keys'
    ' of a dictionary, and their rows to a collection held
    ' by each associated 'item'.
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim sKey, r As Long, IsFound As Boolean
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        sKey = uData(r, 1)
        ' Exclude error values and blanks.
        If Not IsError(sKey) Then
            If Len(CStr(sKey)) > 0 Then IsFound = True
        End If
        ' Write.
        If IsFound Then
            If Not dict.Exists(sKey) Then Set dict(sKey) = New Collection
            dict(sKey).Add r
            IsFound = False ' reset for the next iteration
        Else
            uData(r, 1) = INVALID_STRING
        End If
    Next r
            
    ' Loop through the 'keys' of the dictionary, through the columns
    ' of the jagged array, and through the rows in the collections
    ' and write the required results to the unique array.
    
    Dim rLen As Long: rLen = Len(RESULT_DELIMITER)
            
    Dim Item, tVal, fr As Long, c As Long, cCount As Long, Result As String
            
    For Each sKey In dict.Keys
        cCount = dict(sKey).Count
        fr = dict(sKey)(1)
        If cCount = 1 Then
            uData(fr, 1) = UNIQUE_STRING
        Else
            For t = 1 To tCount
                tVal = tJag(t)(fr, 1)
                For c = 2 To cCount
                    r = dict(sKey)(c)
                    If tJag(t)(r, 1) <> tVal Then Exit For
                Next c
                If c <= cCount Then
                    Result = Result & Titles(t - 1) & RESULT_DELIMITER
                End If
                Debug.Print t, tVal, c, Result
            Next t
            If Len(Result) = 0 Then
                Result = DUPE_STRING
            Else
                Result = Left(Result, Len(Result) - rLen)
            End If
            For c = 1 To cCount
                uData(dict(sKey)(c), 1) = Result
            Next c
            Result = vbNullString ' reset for the next iteration
        End If
    Next sKey
            
    ' Write the values from the unique array to the destination column.
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = rg.Columns(RESULT_COL)
    drg.Value = uData

    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Unique values flagged.", vbInformation

End Sub
```